# Automatically calculating taxes using PayPal Invoicing API

Tags: paypal, invoice

I have an e-commerce application that is using PayPal Payments Standard. Using Merchant account settings, it is possible to set up tax rates for various US states, and they will be correctly added to the order totals (depending on buyer's postal address set in his/her PayPal account) when a payment is processed by PayPal Payment Standard.

Now I am working on integrating PayPal Invoicing API, and I could not find a way to have the taxes calculated automatically and added to the invoice total the same way it is done for PayPal Payments Standard. Can you please let me know how/if this can be done or if I am missing anything?

Thank you!